# Prove there exists a delta

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let  be a real-valued continuous function defined on a set S and suppose that for some c∈S we have f(c) < 0. Prove that there exists  > 0 such that f(x) < 0 ∀∈(c−,c+).

I tried:

To prove - ( is continuous at c)
and (c)<0 ⟹ ∃>0, ()<0
0<|−c|<
Assume  is continuous at c and (c)<0

Then, 
∀>0,∃>0, s.t. |−c|<⟹|()−(c)|<
 s.t.|()|−|(c)|=|()|−(c)≤|()−(c)|<
|()|<+(c)

This is where I stopped I was not sure as to where to go from here or if I am on the right path.

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange! Please describe your attempt or approach to solve the problem and where you are stuck, so that the community can provide an answer relevant to you and to avoid getting your question downvoted/closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f is continuous at x=c. Therefore,

$\forall \epsilon>0, $ there exists a $\delta$ such that if $x \in (c-\delta,c+\delta)$, then $f(x) \in (f(c)-\epsilon,f(c)+\epsilon)$. In particular, you can choose $\epsilon$ to be $-\frac{1}{2} f(c)$, (epsilon is positive, and f(c) is negative), in which case you get $x \in (c-\delta,c+\delta)$, then $f(x) \in (\frac{3}{2}f(c),\frac{1}{2}f(c))$, so f(x)<0 for x.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

From continuity, we can find a $\delta >0$, such that $\forall x \in (c-\delta, c+\delta)$ such that $$|f(x)-f(c)|< -\frac{f(c)}2$$

Try to simplify the last inequality to get an upper bound on $f(x)$ in that neighborhood.